# Can a Logic App File System connector access a file share in an ISE environment without a gateway?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Can a Logic App File System connector access a file share in an ISE environment without a gateway?

The File System connector implies it can access a a file share ... the new connection dialog shows "Root folder path (examples: \MACHINE\myShare or C:\myShare)", but I can't get it to work without installing a local gateway.

Or does it need an ISE variant of the File System connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is ...

Yes, the File System connector can access a file share without an On-Premise Data Gateway

But you need to use the ISE variant of the connector.

*(and at the time of writing (2020-01-13), the ISE variant connector does NOT have all the features of the standard connector)*

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector) shows gateway is required when create the file system.

[image]

Comment: Ta. I found it confusing that in the dialog, the gateway didn't have the red asterix, unlike the other required fields